# Do I have to create a Google Play Console account for the customer to publish his/her app

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I have now an account in [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish) and I am able to publish any app in Google Play.

What I worry about is when I am about to build an app for a customer and he/she wants to publish his/her app as paid app.

To be more clear and for example, someone asked me to build an Android app for him/her with specified price and is ready to pay me for the app. This person is not a developer neither does he/she have an account in Google Play Console. He/She wants his/her app to be published as paid app. I don't know how the rest of the story is supposed to be:

Do I have to create a Google Play Console account for the user with my money?!!

Or the user has to create a Google Play Console acount himself (or herself)?

Or I am supposed to create a Google Play Console account for the user and the user has to pay me 25$ plus the price of my work?

Or what?

Could anybody help me, please? ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd find a lawyer as this comes down to a business/legal decision rather than a development decision.

Personally I would have a separate development account for each customer, as if you develop apps for two very different customers they might not want their competitors, or things not associated with their brand to come up in the "more apps by this developer" section in the Play store.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you would have one master Developer account that you would use to publish all your apps. Each app has its own set of options you would set in the console for that app.
The customer would need to create a merchant account that you would then link to the app in the console.